# How can I avoid passing a reference to a parent object when constructing a new instance of a class?

Tags: c#, class, object, constructor

I have two classes defined as follows.

First one:

```
internal class Content {

   internal Content(Master master) {
        // code omitted
   }

// code omitted
}
```

second one:

```
public class Master {

     internal Content content { get; set; }

     internal Master() {
         // code omitted
     }

// code omitted
}
```

Exposing the Content Class as property of the Master I need to do something like this:

```
Master M = new Master(); 
M.content = new Content(M);
```

Is there a way to do not pass the Master (M) in the Content Consctructor?

Comment: If you have control over the source of Content, you can change it the way your want it to. But why you don't want to pass the Master in the constructor?

Comment: @Luca: Please have a look, I've provided an answer which keeps the dependency of the two classes while it allows easy instantiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably `Content` *needs* a `Master` ? Actually, constructors are a fairly good way of managing this, but if that is a problem, you could also do something like:

```
internal class Content {
    internal void SetMaster(Master master) {this.master = master; }
    //...
}
internal class Master {
    internal void SetContent(Content content) {
        if(content == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
        // maybe handle double-calls...
        this.content = content;
        content.SetMaster(this);
    }
}
...
Master M = new Master();
M.SetContent(new Content());
```

or have `Master` create the `Content` by default. Frankly, though, I'd leave it "as is" until there is an actual "this is a problem".

Answer (score 3):

Why not use lazy initialisation idom?

```
public class Master
{
    private Content _content;

    internal Content content
    {
        get
        {
            if (_content == null)
            {
                _content = new Content(this);
            }
            return _content;
        }
    }
}
```

If `Master` always has to have `content` property set then create `Content` member during construction:

```
public class Master
{
    internal Content content
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    internal Master()
    {
        content = new Content(this);
    }
}
```

You may also use mixed approach:

```
public class Master
{
    internal Content content
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    internal Content GetOrCreateContent()
    {
        if (content == null)
        {
            content = new Content(this);
        }
        return content;
    }

    internal Master()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But you still have to pass the Master instance to the Content's constructor here.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna: Yes, but that is completely internal and irrevelant/invisible to the client code. It is also clean and precisely defined.

Comment: @leppie: That's what's interesting here. The question clearly states: is there a way not to pass that instance to the Content constructor?

Comment: @PiotrJustyna: then I misunderstood. I thought you meant "not to pass the instance to the Content constructor in the client code". The way it is organised internally is not revelant.

Comment: @gwiazdorr I like this method, but I don't want to always instance a Content when a create a Master. Maybe I need to instance a Master without Content. Thanks.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna: please see the new example

Answer (score 1):

Since the the code inside the classes is not shown, I have to make some assumptions what you intended to do. As I could see from your code, the `Content` needs a `Master` and the `Master` can't live without a `Content`.

With the solution I have made for you, you can do the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Master M1 = new Master(); // content instantiated implicitly
    Master M2 = new Content().master; // master instantiated implicitly
}
```

So you can either instantiate the `Master` and `Content` within is instantiated, or vice versa: Instantiate a `Content` and the `Master` is implicitly instantiated.

No matter which alternative you've chosen: The corresponding other object is always instantiated and available via the property variable.

The classes in this example are defined as follows:

```
internal class Content  {  

    internal Master master { get; set; }

    internal Content(Master pmaster) {     
        master=pmaster;
    }

    internal Content() {     
        master = new Master() { content = this };
    }  
}

public class Master {  

    internal Content content { get; set; }  

    internal Master() {     
        content = new Content(this);
    }  

    // this is optional and can be omitted, if not needed:  
    internal Master(Content pcontent) {     
        content = pcontent;
    }  
}
```

Note that I kept the structure you gave in you question as closely as possible, while you have now extra flexibility.